# VB.NET: Are there alternatives to using bitwise logical operators to find matches in records?

Tags: vb.net, binary, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

In some of my Enterprise VB apps, both for Windows and ASP.NET, there are various reports generated, using logical `AND` for determining the recipients of those reports. Each of the reports is assigned a binary coded integer (for lack of a better term), i.e., 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. Recipients are in a SQL database table which includes a field for determining what report each recipient receives, i.e., recipient Snuffy Smiff receives all reports that are assigned binary coded integers 1, 4, and 16. In the recipient table, then, the Reports field for Mr. Smiff contains the sum of those integers, the value 21.

When a report #4 is run, it will run through the list of recipients doing a logical `AND`, and will include Mr. Smiff on the list of recipients because the number 21 `AND`ed with 4 tests `TRUE`. But when report #8 is run, Mr. Smiff is not placed on the list because 8 `AND` 21 is `FALSE`

I hope I have explained that adequately.

Now my problem is that the list of reports keeps growing, and it's getting longer than I had anticipated. There are currently 15 reports, so the binary integer has increased to 16384 for report #15, and with each additional report, that number will double. If this keeps up, it will be larger than even the server can handle.

My question is, is there an alternative method that can be used for selecting the recipients that won't cause an arithmetic overflow?

Comment: Guessing just a table listing the receipients of reports is overly simplistic and hard to maintain?

Comment: I considered that, and was hoping for something a little more efficient. Text field would certainly work, but requires much more space than an integer.

Comment: If the DB field need not be human friendly, an option would be to use a [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-5.0) and store a byte array in the DB.

Comment: @TnTinMn that sounds like a great idea. I'll try it out.

Comment: Storage is cheap. Programmer's billable hours are not cheap.

Comment: @Mary Not real sure what your point is, but as I mentioned in my original post, I am an Enterprise developer, which means my hours are not billable. I am overhead.

Comment: @TnTinMn I haven't had a chance to try your idea yet, but hopefully next week.